# "Обуть" — как жаргон

Tags: этимология, жаргон

Почитал тут интересные рассуждения на тему "обуть-надеть". И в связи с этим вспомнилось жаргонное словечко "обуть" в значении "обмануть кого-то". Интересно, а откуда оно-то появилось? Какая связь?
Заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще версий много, но из известных мне только две мне кажутся убедительными.

~1. Обувь была одним из наиболее ценных предметов быта. Отсюда и всяческое мошенничество. В общем-то почти как сейчас - то фирма левая, то подметка гнилая, то гвозди ржавые... 
~2. От цыган. Лошадь (иногда и корову) прежде чем свести со двора "обували" в матерчатые обмотки или просто привязывали сено. И по следам не найти - и шуму от копыт меньше.

Answer (score 1):

Пардон, господа... По-моему, я угодила по наивности не в те двери...
Ребёнок у вас — раб, Семья — прислуга, рабы, челядь; СЛАВЯНЕ — от лат. = рабы... Как-то всё это подозрительно...
ОБУТЬ = обмотать, окрутить — ОБО+ЪТИ = кругом взять. Для тех, кто действительно заинтересован родным языком, скажу: не отбрасывайте со счетов язык "офеней" (ФЕНЯ), там сохранилось много истинных корней нашего языка, слегонца разбавленных еврейскими.
А что такое жаргонное "обуть", понятно даже цыганскому коню.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы поддержать беседу, добавлю: видел как-то в Москве (конец 80-х -- начало 90-х) рекламу торговой фирмы: "Мы обуем всю Россию". Скорее всего, это было до дефолта, МММ, Инкомбанка, но, уж точно, после ваучеров.